# c while loop entry

Tags: c, while-loop

somebody please explain me why

```
int i=0,j=10;
    while(j>0,i++){
    printf("%d%d",i,j);
    j--;
}
```

will not work and

```
int i=0,j=10;
while(i++,j>0){
    printf("%d%d",i,j);
    j--;
}
```

works.

Also please tell me why

```
int i=0,j=10;
while(j>0,++i){
    printf("%d%d",i,j);
    j--;
}
```

gives an infinite loop ?

thanks and regards

harsha

Comment: This is totally unreadable.... please use the Markup tags at your disposal...

Comment: How can while(j>0,++i){} even compile?

Comment: "while(j>0,i++)" does not compile !!

Comment: @DixonD, @VJ: They *do* compile. Try it for yourself.

Answer (score 16):

In your while-loop condition you use comma operator, which evaluates its parameters and returns the second one. So in your examples:

```
while(j>0,i++) - returns i before it gets incremented; 
                 that is 0, so loop won't execute at all 

while(i++,j>0) - returns (j > 0) - runs as expected

while(j>0,++i) - returns i - will run until i overflows  max int value
```

Comment: The first one exits immediately - it's different from #3.  Otherwise correct.

Comment: Note that in the last example, at the point where `++i` overflows the loop doesn't *necessarily* exit - the behaviour becomes undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on the C [comma operator](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter3/strange_operators.html).  Basically it winds down to the fact that the comma operator returns the result of whatever is on the right side of the comma - so in your first example, i++ returns 0, and the loop ends.  In the third case, ++i is never 0 (at least not for a long time) so you get the infinite loop.  The middle case is ok, since the result of `j>0` is returned from the comma operator, and your loop works as expected.

Comment: I see how this works, but would this usage be considered a "good practice" in c?  Seems a bit obscure.

Comment: Definitely not. Who in the right mind use a comma operator in the while condition?

Comment: The page you linked to suggests that the most common usage is in a `for` loop, although the examples the author gives are even more obscure than the `while` loop shown here. It's difficult to tell which statement is actually being returned in each part of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Yuji: Actually, the condition of a `while` loop is one of the few cases where the comma operator is useful.  It can be the clearest way to write `while (r = func(...), r > x && r < y)` type things without repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the comma operator. The result of the comma operator is the second sub-expression. So `j>0,i++` evaluates to `i++`. `i++` is initially 0, so the loop never executes.

Likewise, `j>0,++i` evaluates to `++i`, which will be non-zero until you overflow, so it appears to loop forever (though really just for a long time).

`i++,j>0` works because the last-subexpression is `j>0`, which is the actual condition that you want. Note that even though the comma operator throws away the result of the first expression (`i++`, in this case) it still evaluates that sub-expression, and so you still get the side-effect (incrementing `i`).

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, you have expressions that include a comma operator. The comma operator evaluates its left operand, then its right operand. The result is that of the right operand.

For the moment, let's consider only your last question:

```
int i=0,j=10;
while(j>0,++i){
    printf("%d%d",i,j);
    j--;
}
```

This should not really be an infinite loop, though it may run just a **bit** longer than expected. Since the result of the comma operator is the result of the *right* operand, this is  waiting for `++i` to become 0. Since it's starting at 0, it's going to cycle though *all* possible values of an `int` before it terminates. With a 16-bit `int`, that would probably take a few minutes. With a 32-bit `int`, it's going to take *quite* a bit longer. With a 64-bit `int`, it *would* be an infinite loop for any practical purpose -- I'm pretty sure I'll die long before it could hope to finish at any rate...

Comment: It will run at least until `i` is equal to `INT_MAX` - at that point, `++i` overflows, which results in undefined behaviour.  This means that *anything* is possible, including an infinite loop (`++i` might well leave `i` unchanged!).

Comment: @caf: In theory, quite true. In fact, you're unlikely to see anything like that -- while there is hardware to provide saturating integers, I've never seen anybody use it for a normal `int`. Given the degree of similarity required between signed and unsigned variants, and the requirement that `unsigned` wrap modulo 2^N-1, I'm not sure there's even hardware that *could* do so, even though it's theoretically possible.

Comment: Well, the saturating functionality would be an attribute of the "ADD" operation - you could imagine an architecture that provided both `Add-With-Saturate` and `Add-With-Wrap` instructions, with a C compiler using the former for signed addition and the latter for unsigned.  Much more likely though is a trap on overflow - if the trap is handled by skipping the trapping instruction, then it would also have the saturating effect (though a program abort is much more likely).